# Why is the fill inverted and leaking in my shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator and drawing using the paint brush tool for the first time. And now I'm trying to fill the shape, but I'm not getting expected behaviour. And would like to understand why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Without fill I drew this shape:
[image: Shape without fill]

Now I fill it:
[image: Filled shape]

Why is the shape inside the strokes not getting filled. Also why is the fill occurring outside of the strokes as well?

Comment: The paths are not closed.

Comment: Read this answer to a related question - [Open path outlines and closed path outlines Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86468/open-path-outlines-and-closed-path-outlines-adobe-illustrator/86508#86508)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your drawing is actually 7 separate path objects. When you fill a shape you fill the area inside the closed path where the last point of each shape is connected to the first. In doing so you can cross the original shape and get color on both sides of it.

What you get is indeed the expected result. Although not what you expected. To fill the area inside you need to revuild it so that you have either 2 closed paths or one closed path and a freestanding stroke. Easiest way to revuild this is to select all objects enable shape builder and make the closed loops you need

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks for this, I understand now.